# 1195 Attempted access of inaccessible method playVideo through a reference with static type NSPv4

Tags: actionscript-3, class

Call:

```
import fl.video.*
import NSPv4;
var playVid:NSPv4 = new NSPv4();
playVid.playVideo(this.parent);
```

---

Class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.SoundMixer;
    import fl.video.*;

    public class NSPv4 extends MovieClip
    {

        var __PARENT;
        var __PARENT1;

        public function playAudio(_PARENT):void
        {
            __PARENT = _PARENT;
            var audioLabel:String = _PARENT.currentLabel;
            var audioLabelNum:String = audioLabel.replace("sct","audio/");
            audioLabelNum +=  ".mp3";
            var vo:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest(audioLabelNum));
            var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
            channel = vo.play();
            channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
        }

        public function playVideo(_PARENT1):void
        {
            __PARENT1 = _PARENT1;
            var videoLabel:String = _PARENT1.currentLabel;
            var videoLabelNum:String = videoLabel.replace("sct","audio/");
            videoLabelNum +=  ".f4v";
            var videoPlayer:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
            videoPlayer.source = videoLabelNum;
            _PARENT1.addChild(videoPlayer);
        }



        public function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            MovieClip(__PARENT).nextFrame();
        }

    }
}
```

---

Can call the playAudio with no problems but when I try playVideo() I get the following error:

`1195 Attempted access of inaccessible method playVideo through a reference with static type NSPv4`

I set up a separate class for the video to stand alone without the playAudio() function and this works too.

Most confused!

Comment: I just ran this code and I am not getting the error you are describing. Only errors I got were something about the label, but that is because the movie clip doesn't exist for me.

Comment: I've made both the functions static which seems to have worked out the problem. Not exactly an elegant solution but hey.